# How to generate diacritized vowel table automatically?

Tags: java, php, .net, wolfram-mathematica, diacritics

I want to have the table of vowels with [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), but don't want to search symbol tables manually.

Is it possible to generate this table by crossing the list of vowels and the list of [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) in some of the following languages: Java, PHP, Wolfram Mathematica, .NET languages and so on?

I need to have characters (unicode) as output.

**Java Solution**

I found that there are a special Unicode feature for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization

Java supports it since 1.6 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

So, the sample code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vowels = "aeiou";
    char[] diacritics = {'\u0304', '\u0301', '\u0300', '\u030C'};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int v=0; v<vowels.length(); ++v) {
        for(int d=0; d<diacritics.length; ++d) {
            sb.append(vowels.charAt(v));
            sb.append(diacritics[d]);

            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(vowels.charAt(v));
        sb.append('\n');
    }

    String ans = Normalizer.normalize(sb.toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFC);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ans);
}
```

I.e. we just put combining diacritics after vowels and then apply normalization to the string.

Comment: You can try to extract the information from http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt  I assume you only want Roman letters.  Anything matching LATIN SMALL|CAPITAL LETTER A|E|I|O|U WITH should be relevant.  I do not know how robust this is and if you want things like ø.  Also, beware that Mathematica doesn't properly support Unicode outside the Basic Multilingual Plane: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597013/reading-an-utf-8-encoded-text-file-in-mathematica

Comment: Also, what about things like æ?  Do you consider it a vowel (it certainly is in Norwegian) or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I haven't completely deciphered what Szabolcs' code is doing, but in this particular case this seems to produce the same result in Mathematica using slightly less code

```
data = Import["http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt", "Lines"];

codes = Cases[data, 
 b_String /; StringMatchQ[
  b, ___ ~~ "LATIN " ~~ "CAPITAL" | "SMALL" ~~ " LETTER " ~~ 
   "A" | "E" | "I" | "O" | "U" ~~ " WITH " ~~ ___] :> 
    FromDigits[StringTake[b, 4], 16], Infinity];

FromCharacterCode[codes]
```

which produces

```
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜàáâãäåèéêëìíîïòóôõöøùúûüĀāĂăĄąĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĨĩĪīĬ\
ĭĮįİŌōŎŏŐőŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųƗƟƠơƯưǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǞǟǠǡǪǫǬǭǺǻǾǿȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍ\
ȎȏȔȕȖȗȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯȰȱȺɆɇɨᶏᶒᶖᶙḀḁḔḕḖḗḘḙḚḛḜḝḬḭḮḯṌṍṎṏṐṑṒṓṲṳṴṵṶṷṸṹṺṻẚẠạẢảẤấẦầẨ\
ẩẪẫẬậẮắẰằẲẳẴẵẶặẸẹẺẻẼẽẾếỀềỂểỄễỆệỈỉỊịỌọỎỏỐốỒồỔổỖỗỘộỚớỜờỞởỠỡỢợỤụỦủỨứỪừỬửỮ\
ữỰựⱥⱸⱺꝊꝋꝌꝍ"
```

Answer (score 2):

I digged up some old Mathematica code I had, I'm going to paste it here. You can use it any way to please. Bugs to be expected!

```
uninames = 
  StringSplit[
   Import["http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt", "Text"], 
   "\n"];

uniNameList = ({ToExpression["16^^" <> First[#]], 
      StringJoin@Riffle[Rest[#], "\n"]} & /@ 
    DeleteCases[
     Flatten /@ 
       Split[StringSplit[#, "\t" .., All] & /@ Take[uninames, All], 
        First[#2] === "" &] /. "" -> Sequence[], 
     x_ /; StringTake[First[x], 1] === "@"]);

uniRangeList = {FromDigits[#1, 16], 
     FromDigits[#3, 15], #2} & @@@ (Rest /@ 
     Select[StringSplit[#, "\t"] & /@ uninames, First[#] == "@@" &]);

Clear[unicodeName]
Set[unicodeName[#1], #2] & @@@ uniNameList;
Set[unicodeName[n_Integer /; #1 <= n <= #2], #3] & @@@ uniRangeList;
unicodeName[s_String /; StringLength[s] === 1] := 
 unicodeName[First@ToCharacterCode[s]]
unicodeName[_] := ""
```

Now we can do either

```
vowelCodes = Select[
  uniNameList[[All, 1]], 
  StringMatchQ[unicodeName[#], 
    "LATIN " ~~ "SMALL" | "CAPITAL" ~~ " LETTER " ~~ 
     "A" | "E" | "I" | "O" | "U" ~~ " WITH" ~~ ___] &
  ]
```

(which doesn't include things like æ), or

```
vowelCodes = Select[
  uniNameList[[All, 1]], 
  StringMatchQ[unicodeName[#], 
    "LATIN " ~~ "SMALL" | "CAPITAL" ~~ " LETTER " ~~ 
     "A" | "E" | "I" | "O" | "U" ~~ ___] &
  ]
```

(manual filtering needed in this case to get rid of things like ESH - ʃ)

Then you can do `FromCharacterCode /@ vowelCodes`, but the default font might not show all characters.

The first approach gives me

```
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜàáâãäåèéêëìíîïòóôõöøùúûüĀāĂăĄąĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĨĩĪīĬ\
ĭĮįİŌōŎŏŐőŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųƗƟƠơƯưǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǞǟǠǡǪǫǬǭǺǻǾǿȀȁȂȃȄȅȆȇȈȉȊȋȌȍ\
ȎȏȔȕȖȗȦȧȨȩȪȫȬȭȮȯȰȱȺɆɇɨᶏᶒᶖᶙḀḁḔḕḖḗḘḙḚḛḜḝḬḭḮḯṌṍṎṏṐṑṒṓṲṳṴṵṶṷṸṹṺṻẚẠạẢảẤấẦầẨ\
ẩẪẫẬậẮắẰằẲẳẴẵẶặẸẹẺẻẼẽẾếỀềỂểỄễỆệỈỉỊịỌọỎỏỐốỒồỔổỖỗỘộỚớỜờỞởỠỡỢợỤụỦủỨứỪừỬửỮ\
ữỰựⱥⱸⱺꝊꝋꝌꝍ"
```

Please note that this filtering by Unicode names is not robust, and the table might easily be missing some vowels (e.g. I can't seem to find a dotless i above)